# EasyMock: Exception asserting any class in hierarchy

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I would like to write a JUnit test asserting to an exception. In my case, my expectation is catching a DataAccessException. However, DataAccessException is an abstract class and my code could throw any concrete class which extends from DataAccessException.

This is my code, using JUnit rule:

```
@Rule
public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void testDelete_fail() {
    EasyMock.expect(testSubject.delete(EasyMock.anyObject()))
            .andThrow(new DataAccessException("..."));

    exception.expect(DataAccessException.class);
    testSubject.delete(id);         
}
```

As you know, I can not create a new instance of an abstract class. It means, I'm not able to fill an argument for andThrow method. If I try to build with DuplicateKeyException, which one extends from DataAccessException, I got an error:

```
AssertionError: Expected test to throw an instance of org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
```

Any ideas?, I would prefer something using EasyMock. Thanks

[image: Hierarchy of DataAccessException]

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick would be `createNiceMock(DataAccessException.class)`. But in fact, `new DataAccessException("...") {}` would also work.

Comment: Hi, I tried using EasyMock.createNiceMock(DataAccessException.class) but I got another error (NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V). The way that temporarily fixed my problem was creating a  new instance DataIntegrityViolationException. My key problem was that I forgot to call EasyMock.replay. By the way, thanks for your answer